# How can I log into all my signed up Stack Exchange accounts at once?

Tags: support, login

As I am not using Google or Facebook as a logon service, how can I log into all my accounts at once?

I am pretty sure this has been asked and answered before, unfortunately I wasn't able to find it...

Answer (score 2):

You can use StackExchange as central auth service itself. After you are logged in on one service, it should log you in to all other sites you visit.